# Why betweenness centrality differs in igraph?

Tags: r, igraph

I'm not a pro programmer, but I've been learning on my own. I have a problem with betweenness centrality. I have an undirected weighted graph of 28 actors, in an adjacency matrix. When I run the code `betweenness(PG_Network4, v = V(PG_Network4), directed = FALSE, nobigint = TRUE, normalized = TRUE)` the results differs significantly than those I ran in UCINET, Pajek, Gephi (all of them are the same results). What is weird is that, if I do not load my network into R as "weighted" then the results are the same. And the differences are really considerable, for instance, in `igraph`, those nodes at the 2nd, 3rd, 4th (betweenness degree) in UCINET, Gephi or Pajek passes to the 6th, 10th, and 13th positions. What am I doing wrong here? I thought it was the weighted specification, but UCINET considers that, and still maintain the same results than Pajek and Gephi.

Thank you so much.

Comment: It still sounds like it comes down to the edge weights. You can test this by changing the weights. If UCINET really does make use of the weights, then the betweeness values should change as well.

Answer (score 0):

The issue you're having is caused by the weighted edges in the graph. UCINET and the other programs make use of it automatically, but in igraph you need to specifically define it in the betweenness function. Add edge weight to your graph: E(g)$weight <- sum(ecount(g)).

Then you can call it in the function betweenness(g, weights = E(g)$weight).

This should resolve your issue and get your values to match up with the other programs.